# Intuition behind SOCP and why it sometimes can be solved more efficiently than without transforming it into a SOCP?

Tags: cone

I was doing an assignment regarding turbine placements, where one has to write and solve a maximisation problem. As I was reading into the topic, I came across the fact that I could transform the constraints into an equivalent $\sqrt{...^{2}+...^{2}} \leq ...$ form, which I believe is called a SOCP.

Although, we will not touch upon this topic, it did spark my curiosity. Therefore, I have some basic questions that I am unable to find by myself and thus hereby I would like to ask them to you all.

1. What is the intuition behind it that a SOCP formulation can be solved more efficiently?
2. Why does SOCP give relatively stable solutions (i.e. if I change parameters the maximum of the objective function does not vary significantly, but remain rather stable).
3. Why doesn't the solver transform the problem automatically into a SOCP one, if SOCP is so much better?
4. Is a SOCP formulation **always** better (i.e. meaning are there instances where one is better off not transforming the constraints into a SOCP)?

Thanks all!

Comment: I think it would be help if you let us know what are you comparing SOCP with? Also, I personally feel that 2 is still too vague, consider adding a small problem to illustrate stability more clearly. A general saying I hear from academics and numerical software developers is that, if your problem can be posed as a LP, then dont transform it into a QP. If the problem can be posed as a QP, then dont transform it into a SOCP. If the problem can be posed as SOCP, then dont transform it into a SDP.

Comment: @batwing The general saying yoiu'vre heard may be bad advice with regard to using QP instead of SOCP.  SOCP can be better behaved numerically die to not squaring the condition number, or basically, dealing with the square root of the QP condition number. "On  formulating  quadratic functions in optimization models" by Erling Andersen https://docs.mosek.com/whitepapers/qmodel.pdf

Comment: Erling Andersen is @ErlingMOSEK

Comment: @MarkL.Stone- Interesting, thanks!

Comment: Some non SOCP based interior-point methods can struggle with infeasible QPs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Whether a given formulation is faster / more stable than another depends on the software you use to solve either.

> What is the intuition behind it that a SOCP formulation can be solved more efficiently?

Here are a few reasons. For more details, you can have a look at the [Mosek modeling cookbook](https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/index.html) or the seminal book of [Ben Tal & Nemirovskii, Lectures on Modern Convex Optimization](https://www2.isye.gatech.edu/%7Enemirovs/lmco_run.pdf).

- **Cones do not require derivatives.**

  If you write a constraint $\sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}} \leq z$ an give it to, say, Ipopt (which is uses derivatives), it may fail when $x, y, z$ are zero (because the square root is non-differentiable at zero). On the other hand, conic solvers do not work with derivatives, and will not fail.
- **Second-Order Cones are convex.**

  Consider the constraint $x^{2} + y^{2} \leq z^{2}, z \geq 0$. The quadratic part $x^{2} + y^{2} - z^{2} \leq 0$ is not convex, and some solvers may fail to detect that (in general, it's NP-hard to determine whether a given function is convex over its domain). If you write that same constraint as an SOC, you know intrinsically that it is convex.
  In fact, if your problem is convex, there's a 99.99% chance you can write it as a conic optimization problem. You can look at the [Mosek modeling cookbook](https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/index.html) and its [conic modeling cheatsheet](https://docs.mosek.com/cheatsheets/conic.pdf) for such examples.
- **Conic duality**

  The dual of a (convex) conic optimization problem is also a convex conic optimization problem and, in most cases of interest, we know how to write it. That is not true in general for convex optimization problems (for instance, the Lagrangian dual, in general, is non-convex).

  Thus, efficient algorithms exist for the resolution of conic optimization problems. They include, among others, interior-point methods and the Alternating Direction Method of Multipliers (ADMM). The former are implemented in,  e.g., [Mosek](https://www.mosek.com/), Sedumi, [ECOS](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/papers/ecos.html); the latter in OSQP or [SCS](https://github.com/cvxgrp/scs).

> Why does SOCP give relatively stable solutions (i.e. if I change parameters the maximum of the objective function does not vary significantly, but remain rather stable).

This behavior depends on which algorithm you use to solve your problem.
Interior-point methods are likely to give you a similar solution if you do not change the parameters much. Others may behave differently, especially if your problem has multiple optimal solutions.

> Why doesn't the solver transform the problem automatically into a SOCP one, if SOCP is so much better?

Several people advocate for doing so.

- MOSEK will always reformulate everything using conic formulations.
- Disciplined Convex Programming tools such as [CVX](https://cvxr.com/cvx/), [cvxpy](https://cvxpy.org), etc. allow to formulate a problem using convex optimization paradigms, and will reformulate it as a conic optimization problem under the hood.

However, it only makes sense to use a conic formulation if you have a conic solver at hand. For instance, Ipopt does not support conic constraints.

> Is a SOCP formulation always better (i.e. meaning are there instances where one is better off not transforming the constraints into a SOCP)?

My general experience is that conic formulations tend to be faster and numerically more robust. Thus, I would recommend using conic formulations when possible. Sometimes doing so helps realizing that a problem is actually convex (which is a good thing).

For completeness, here are a couple of counter-examples to this rule:

- If your problem has linear constraints and a convex quadratic objective, you can solve it using the [simplex algorithm](https://www.rand.org/pubs/papers/P1205.html). Doing so can be advantageous if, e.g., you need to warm-start. This is particularly true when solving Mixed-Integer Quadratic Programs, or when solving multiple instances that do not vary too much.
- Formulating a quadratic constraint (or objective) as a SOC requires computing a matrix factorization. Sometimes, this may result in much denser problems, which are then harder to solve.

  The converse can also happen: if you have a quadratic objective $x^{T}Qx$ where $Q = M^{T}M$ for some low-rank matrix $M$, then an SOC formulation may be much faster (though you could also introduce $y = Mx$ and minimize $y^{T}y$).

Comment: Excellent reply. I would add one thing i.e. the Nesterov-Todd primal-dual algorithm for optimizing over the symmetric cones.  This algorithm is employed by at least 99% of all commercial SOCP codes and is the cause of their efficiency. See  https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10107-002-0349-3 and the references therein.